# Use the function "mod" in the instructions "if" and "select case"

Tags: fortran

I wrote a little code in Fortran. But the code doesn't behave as I thought, and I can figure out where is the problem.
I will not put the code here because it has 1200 lines but here its philosophy:

- I create a 3D grid represented by a four dimensional table (I stock a vector of 2 elements on each point of the grid, corresponding at the nature of the site and who is occupying the site). This grid represents what we call a crystal (where atoms can be found periodically)
- When this grid is constructed, the code scans each point of this grid and it looks to the neighboring sites to count the different type of atoms or the vacancies.

For this last point, I use a triple imbricated loop which permit to explore the different sites and I check the different neighboring site using either the **if** or the **select case** instructions. As I want my grid to be periodic, I have the function mod in the argument of the **if** or the **select case**.
The problem is sometimes, It found a different element in a neighboring site that the actual element in this specific neighboring site. As an example:

> In the two ouput files where all the coordinates are written with the
>   element type I have grid(0,0,1)=-1 (which correspond to a empty site).
>   But while the code is looking to the neighboring sites of grdi(0,0,1) It tells that there is actually an element indexed 2 in grid(0,0,1).

I look carefully to the block in the triple implemented loop, but it seems fine.
**I would like to know if anyone has already meet this kind of problem, or know if there is some problems using mod in a if or select case argument ?**

If some of you want to look closer, I can send you the code, with some explanations.

Comment: Indeed putting 1200 lines here would be bad, but without some minimal code example there's really nothing to help me understand your problem.  Can you reduce the problem to something manageable but still sharing the issue?  See [mcve].

Comment: Never encountered a problem with mod in if or select cases.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are usually dimensioned as:
REAL(KIND=8),DIMENSION(0:N) ::A
or
REAL(KIND=8),DIMENSION(N) :: A

In the later example, they are assumed to start at 1.
You could also go (-N:N) or (10:191)

If you use the compiler switch '-check bounds' or ;-check all' you will see if you are going outside the array/etc. This is not an uncommon thing to get hosed up, but the compiler will abort quickly when the dimension is outside.
Once it works then removed the -check bounds and/or -check all.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your consideration francescalus and haraldkl.
It was not related to the dimension of arrays Holmz, but thank you to try to help

It seems I finally succeed to fix it. I will post an over answer If I fully understand why it was not working properly.
Apparently, it was related to the combination of **a different argument order in a call procedure and the subroutine header** + a declaration in the subroutine with **intent(inout)**.
It was like the intent(inout) was masking the problem. But It a bit strange for me.

Some explanations about the code :
As I said, the code create a 3D grid where each intersection of the 3D grid correspond to a crystallographic site. I attribute a value at each site -1 for an empty site, 1 for a crystal atom (0 if there is a vacancy instead of a crystal atom), 2,3,4,5 for different impurities. Actually, the empty sites and the sites which received crystal atoms are not of the same type, that's why an empty site and a vacancy are distinguished. The impurities can only occupied the empty site and are forbidden to occupied a crystal site.

The aim of the code is to explore the configurational space of the system, in other words all the possible distribution we can obtained with the different elements. To do so I start from a initial configuration and I choose randomly to site (respecting the rules of occupation) and I virtually switch them. I calculate the energy of the old an new configurations, if the new has a lower energy I keep it, if not, i keep the old one. The calculus of the energy is based on the knowledge of the environment of each vacancies and impurities, so we need to know their neighbors. And I repeat the all procedure again and again to converge to the most stable (so the most probable) configuration.

The next step is to include the temperature effect, and to add the second type of empty sites.
Have a nice day,

M.